# click event doesn't bubble up on image thats nested in

Tags: javascript

when i click on the image it doesnt bubble up to the parent which does have the "questions" class and make the if condition true, isnt it supposed to work that way?

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(event){
  if(event.target.classList.contains('questions')){
    const answers = event.target.nextElementSibling;
    answers.style.display = answers.style.display === "block"? "none" : "block";
  }
  else{
    document.querySelectorAll('dd').forEach((dd)=>dd.style.display= "none")
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="faq-item">
    <dt class="questions">qstn
        <img class="questionsArrow" src="https://placehold.co/50?text=%3C%3E%3C" >
    </dt>
    <dd class="answers">answr</dd>
</div>
```

Comment: It's quite unclear what you're trying to do, or what doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Your `img` doesn't have a class `questions`.   You maybe want to do `if (event.target.closest('questions')) { ` instead.

Comment: Your event handler is listening on `document` - so the event *has already bubbled* ... all the way up to `document`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does bubble up to the element with the `questions` class, but that element isn't `event.target`, the one you're testing. That's the `img` ([`mdn: target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)). The element with the `questions` class is `event.target`'s parent. The best way to get it is probably the [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) method (in case you change the HTML slightly):

```
document.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    const questions = event.target.closest(".questions");
    if (questions) {
        const answers = questions.nextElementSibling;
        answers.style.display = answers.style.display === "block" ? "none" : "block";
    } else {
        document.querySelectorAll("dd").forEach((dd) => (dd.style.display = "none"));
    }
});
```

The `closest` method accepts a CSS selector and finds the first element matching that selector, starting with the one you call it on, then if that doesn't match trying its parent, and if the parent doesn't match, the parent's parent, etc.

---

In a comment you asked:

> can u explain this line " It does bubble up to that element, but that element isn't event.target, that's the img...

`target` is always the element the event was targeted at, regardless of whether your handler is on that element or one of its ancestors. So if the click is on `img`, `event.target` is the `img`. But the event **does** bubble, and any handlers attached to its ancestor elements (or the document) will get triggered (as yours is). That doesn't change what `event.target` is, though. Your event handler on `document` is only called once, not repeatedly for the `img` and each of its ancestors.

Comment: thnk u sm. can u explain this line " It does bubble up to that element, but that element isn't event.target, that's the img. It's event.target's parent" some more? im kinda confused

Comment: @mobx - `target` is always the element the event was targeted at, regardless of whether your handler is on that element or one of its ancestors. So if the click is on `img`, `event.target` is the `img`. But the event **does** bubble, and any handlers attached to its ancestor elements (or the document) will get triggered. That doesn't change what `event.target` is, though. Your event handler on `document` is only called **once**, not repeatedly for the `img` and each of its ancestors.